# Memory leak in Windows Service - InterceptableDbCommand

Tags: c#, service, memory-leaks

I've got problem with memory leak. When I run my application in window mode, everything is OK, but when I host it as a Windows Service there is a problem with memory leak. It's not releasing DbContext and another objects because they are referenced to InterceptableDbCommand which is GC Root. InterceptableDbCommand contains queries to database generated by Entity Framework.

What is diffrience in relasing memory between application and windows service mode?

Answer (score 0):

Generally Garbage Collector releases memory if its 'Gen 0' going to overflow (Large object heap also can trigger GC). AFAIK Garbage Collector uses the same approach to release the memory for both .Net Applications and Windows Services.

If there is a memory leak probably it should exists in both Application and Windows Service (if the workflow is exactly the same). May be you have the same issue with the Application, but you don't notice because of its workflow nature. How did you test it for memory leaks?

**More importantly:** Make sure you dispose InterceptableDbCommand and all other disposable objects.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found cause. There was attribute [STAThread] in Main method, after deleting it everything works just fine.